# "Msg: The module win_ping was redirected to ansible.windows.win_ping, which could not be loaded "

Tags: ansible

I tried to install the ansible.windows collections using "ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.windows", but  I'm getting error as "Error! Unkown error when attempt to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/':nonnuneric port:xxxx"

Answer (score 0):

I'm part of the Ansible Community Team at Red Hat, sorry that something isn't working.

I'm not aware of any problems with galaxy.ansible.com. Though it's possible there was a temporary issue

Could you run with debug enabled and paste the full output when you run `ansible-galaxy collection install -vvvv ansible.windows`

That will also tell us which version of `ansible` you are using.

Comment: ansible-galaxy [core 2.12.5]                                  python version = 3.8.10

Answer (score 0):

Need to install ansible.windows with command:

`"ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.windows"`

then you can check with

`"ansible-galaxy collection list"`

then the

`"ansible -i inventory host -m win_ping"`

again ... should work.